# When a distance in Dynamic Time Warping is said to be 'short' or 'optimal'?

Tags: time-series, clustering, structural-equation-modeling, distance, dynamic-time-warping

I'm doing a research on *Dynamic Time Warping* and I wasn't able to find a certain number to be considered an optimal distance.

I wonder if there exists some value or it depends on the datasets concerned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A distance of zero would be a perfect match between the two signals, and the distance cannot be negative. I don't think there is an upper limit on the distance as it could be increased by signals that differ in intensity even more (such as multiplying one of the signals by a constant greater than 1 before performing the DTW), or signals that are even more missaligned than the ones you have just checked.